# Как настроить nginx + gunicorn + web.py?

Tags: python, nginx, gunicorn

Начал крутить связку nginx + gunicorn + web.py

файл var/www/test.py файл выглядит так

```
import web
urls = (
    '/', 'hello'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals()).wsgifunc()
class hello:
    def GET(self):
        return "<h1>Hello World!</h1>"
```

команда gunicorn test:app запускается и дает следующее на выходе

```
[2017-12-27 19:26:53 +0000] [9741] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2017-12-27 19:26:53 +0000] [9741] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (9741)
[2017-12-27 19:26:53 +0000] [9741] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-12-27 19:26:53 +0000] [9745] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9745
```

настройка nginx /etc/nginx/sites-available/test.conf выглядит следующим образом

```
server {
    listen 80;
    #server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/;
    access_log /var/www/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/error.log;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Перезагружаю nginx но вижу стандартное приветствие «Welcome to nginx!»

Помогите запуститься пожалуйста

P.S. использовал этот https://habrahabr.ru/post/267097/ туториал

Comment: `ln -s ../sites-available/test.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.conf` забыли выполнить наверно

Comment: `server_name` почему закомментировали?

Comment: @andreymal
символическую ссылку делал... а server_name закоментировал потому что не знаю чего там писать